# How to express this meaning by using "right" as a noun?

Tags: meaning

> If you have read the whole book, you are in a better position to explain it.(self-made)

Can I change the sentence to be "if you..., you have more right to explain it". If not, how to rewrite the sentence with "right" as a noun?

Comment: Yes it would work, but to be clear you should say "more OF A right to explain it".

Comment: As the answers show, you can easily change the sentence to use ‘right’—but the meaning of the sentence will be completely different, of course. Having (more of) a right to do something is not the same as being in a (better) position to do it. I cannot really think of a context where it would be natural to say that someone has a _right_ to explain a book. You have a right to remain silent, to bear arms (if you live in the States), to an attorney, to live free of prosecution, etc.—but a right to explain a book? It makes much more sense to be in a (better) _position_ to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering "better or more of a right" than whom or what?  There's some ambiguity there.

If there is no answer for that, then you can say **"If you have read the whole book, you have the right to explain it."**

Comment: Aside from the fact that the sentence expresses fallacious reasoning and a very strange concept of _rights_, the grammatical issue is whether _right_ should be used as a gradable mass noun (_have more right to_ `VP`) or a gradable count noun (_have more of a right to_ `VP`). I've heard both used, but the second sounds better to my American ear.

Answer (score 0):

"More of a right to explain it" would be a bit more clear, but the expression itself is perfectly fine.

Comment: *More right to explain it* is perfectly grammatical and, IMHO, perfectly idiomatic. But so is *more of a right*.

Comment: I tend to agree with criticism.

Comment: Well, since, you natives do not agree on this, I better never use "have right"or "have more of a right to explain". I will save them in other contexts, like "you have more of a right to chastize the government than him, because you have done so much for it".